# 'flutter packages get' fails with node_preamble complaint

Tags: flutter, dart

After trying to add a new package to pubspec.yaml and run 'flutter packages get', the following error occurs (10 retries):

Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (2 tries left)
Because flutter_tools depends on node_preamble 1.4.8 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.

I have tried:
- removing the new package from pubspec.yaml (flutter_sticky_header: "^0.3.4")
- changing the flutter channel to stable, dev, master
- creating a new Visual Studio flutter project during which the new project runs packages get automatically. (The new project acts the same even though the dependencies are pretty basic.)
- killing dart processes
- restarting my mac

So far, a few hours spent on this with no success. Any comments are appreciated.

```
name: offerings  
description: A new Flutter project.  

version: 1.0.0+1  

environment:  
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"  

dependencies:  
  flutter:  
    sdk: flutter  

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2  

dev_dependencies:  
  flutter_test:  
    sdk: flutter  


flutter:  

uses-material-design: true
```

flutter doctor -v before removing the bin/cache folder is all green except   for the intelliJ check which is no problem since I use that only for Java  development.
After the cache delete the doctor -v command starts to download the sdk   and the same error occurs.
rm -rf cache
ken$ flutter doctor -v
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine   617938024315e205f26ed72ff0f0647775fa6a71...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time   Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left   Speed
 36  201M   36 74.1M    0     0   867k      0  0:03:57  0:01:27  0:02:30   877k
 63  201M   63  128M    0     0   857k      0  0:04:00  0:02:33  0:01:27   1058k
 84  201M   84  169M    0     0   819k      0  0:04:11  0:03:32  0:00:39   763k
 84  201M   84  170M    0     0   819k      0  0:04:11  0:03:33  0:00:38   893k
 85  201M   85  171M    0     0   819k      0  0:04:11  0:03:34  0:00:37   890k
 86  201M   86  173M    0     0   819k      0  0:04:11  0:03:37  0:00:34   820k
 86  201M   86  174M    0     0   819k      0  0:04:11  0:03:38  0:00:33   785k
100  201M  100  201M    0     0   777k      0  0:04:25  0:04:25 --:--:--   871k
Building flutter tool...

Because flutter_tools depends on node_preamble 1.4.8 which doesn't match   any versions, version solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9   tries left)

Comment: Can you update your question with all of your pubspec dependencies?

Comment: Updated with dependencies.

Comment: When you run this you get the error? Try `flutter clean`.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong while downloading the dart sdk. Can you delete the cache folder inside bin and then run flutter doctor again? Please check this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12666

Comment: Please check: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15101

can you please post your flutter doctor -v output?

Comment: Added the flutter doctor -v output after deleting the bin/cache. Still the same error.

Comment: Going to try reinstalling flutter and dart.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I can't explain all of the reasons why, but everything is working again.  
Here is what I did:  
- Reinstalled flutter. This allowed me to run 'flutter channel dev' again.  
- I tried 'flutter packages get' again but it complained about being unable find   package dev_dependencies. The copy/pasted file above doesn't show it, but there   was a space before the dev_dependencies, ie. ' dev_dependencies'. I removed that    and the 'flutter packages get' ran correctly. This is the best explanation that I have.